# How to Replace Part of Style Background:url in Blogger Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

Firstly, apologies, I'm a complete novice, I'm sure I'll be using the wrong terminology somewhere.

I am trying to increase the resolution of the images in my Recent Posts widget and Random Posts widget.

I need a piece of code that replaces part of the "background:url" of "a class="mag-thumb", the code needs to replace "/s72-c/" in the url with "/s300/"

e.g.

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-0STAMmB_Qws/W3bMkXzc2aI/AAAAAAAAKec/zxATGYlKdFM61Y343kTGa1C5FNli11Y9ACLcBGAs/s72-c/s_tronic2_en__download.jpg

would become

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-0STAMmB_Qws/W3bMkXzc2aI/AAAAAAAAKec/zxATGYlKdFM61Y343kTGa1C5FNli11Y9ACLcBGAs/s300/s_tronic2_en__download.jpg

I am using this theme -> https://www.themexpose.com/2017/09/seoboost-best-seo-optimized-blogger.html

On a test blog here -> https://andybuckdetailing.blogspot.com/

There is already a piece of jQuery code running on the site to do exactly what I want, but only for the Popular Posts widget. However, due to the way the Popular Posts widget is written I can't just copy and modify for the Random and Recent Posts widgets.

Popular Posts has an img src, whereas Recent Posts uses a style background.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

```css
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dimension = 150;
    $('#PopularPosts1,#PopularPosts2,#PopularPosts3').find('img').each(function(n, image) {
        var image = $(image);
        image.attr({
            src: image.attr('src').replace(/s72-c/, 's' + dimension)
        })
    })
});


//]]>
</script>
```

I've tried @Bassam 's solution below, but may have input it into the code incorrectly, I placed it directly below the script above, formatted like this:

```css
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mag-thumb').each(function () {
        var img = this.style.background;
        this.style.background = img.replace('/s72-c/', '/s300/');
});

//]]>
</script>
```

Second try at @Bassam 's solution.

```css
    </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mag-thumb').each(function () {
        var img = this.style.background;
        this.style.background = img.replace('/s72-c/', '/s300/');
});

//]]>
</script>

</body>
```

Third try at @Bassam's solution, this one's live on the test blog linked above if that helps anyone determine why it's not working.

```
    </div>

<script>
//<![CDATA[
    $('.mag-thumb').each(function () {
        var img = this.style.background;
        this.style.background = img.replace('/s72-c/', '/s300/');
    });
//]]>
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to manipulate background attribute of `.mag-thumb`

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
     $('.mag-thumb').each(function () {
       var img = this.style.background;
       this.style.background = img.replace('/s72-c/', '/s300/');
    });
  }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Bassam thanks so much for replying, unfortunately I can't get your code to work. It's probably my fault not placing it where it should be.

I placed it under the other piece of code in my original question, like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.mag-thumb').each(function () {
     var img = this.style.background;
     this.style.background = img.replace('/s72-c/', '/s300/');
});

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @AndyBuck, as recent posts widgets rendered by javascript, you should place the code after the last javascript tag on the page, place it before `</body>`

Comment: Thanks @Bassam, I've added it exactly as you suggested and it still isn't working for some reason. I'll keep trying. Thanks so much for taking the time to help!

Comment: You can try my answer, Updated